# Push an incremental INT to a LABEL

Tags: python, tkinter

I need a window with an input box and an output box.
In the input box I set a number (int) the program has to multiply it by 2 every one(1) second and write the result on the outbox.

I started with this:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

master = tk.Tk()

#####################################

int1 = 2 #this is the number I need to write in the input box

#######################################
    
abc = tk.IntVar(master, value= int1)
#print(abc.get())
out = abc.get()
mylabel= tk.Label(master,  text= out)
mylabel.pack()

#####################################
master.mainloop()


while int1 <= 100:
    time.sleep(1)
    int1 += 2
    print(int1)

# I tryed to integrate this block above but without success.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `master.mainloop()` blocks until the window is closed. So when your `while` loop starts the user cannot see the output anymore. The solution is to use `master.after` to schedule a function to run after one second.

You also had mixed problems with the `IntVar` that would cause it not to be updated, so I've rewritten how IntVar and Label are created.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

master = tk.Tk()

#####################################

start_value = 2 #this is the number I need to write in the input box

#######################################
    
counter = tk.IntVar(master, value=start_value)
# Use `textvariable=` instead of `text=`, or the counter won't update!
mylabel= tk.Label(master, textvariable=counter)
mylabel.pack()


def increment_number():
    # Get the value from IntVar and updated it.
    # The label will update automatically because we created it
    # with `textvariable=counter`.
    counter.set(counter.get() * 2)
    # Continue increment the number after one second.
    master.after(1000, increment_number)

# Start incrementing the number after one second.
master.after(1000, increment_number)
#####################################
master.mainloop()
```

As for the input box, I'd suggest you give it a try yourself first. Feel free to create another question if you run into problems with that part.